# Django oscar custom template file structure

Tags: django-templates, django-oscar

I'm trying to write my custom template for django oscar. I have completly different template structure from original oscar's template. But for now it uses many default oscar views.

The problem is that template path is hardcoded in oscar's default view. I.e.

`template_name = 'catalogue/browse.html'`

And I need something like:

`template_name = 'anotherdir/index.html'`

What is the best/easiest way to override this template paths and leave default oscar views logic?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to extend the views for which you want to change the templates, then just override the "template_name" variable.

eg:

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.views import ProductCategoryView as OscarProductCategoryView

class ProductCategoryView(OscarProductCategoryView):
    template_name = 'anotherdir/index.html'
```